# Make android app backround change when button is pushed, and is on value true or false

Tags: java, android, button, background

In my android app I have a button named "button1". When you click the button a boolean gets either true or false and displays some text appropriately for either true or false.

What I would like to have it do is along with change the text I would like it to change the background based on whether the value after you click the button is true or false.

I have tried anything and everything I can think of so any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Below is the code without any modifications to try and make the background change.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Random r = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void calculate(View v){
    EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
    String num1=(number1text.getText().toString());
    String ans=num1;

    TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);    
    boolean value = r.nextBoolean();
    if(value==true){
    answer.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    answer.setText("It is a cause for celebration!                    So CELEBRATE!");}
    if(value==false){
    answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    answer.setText("Exciting, but not a cause for celebration!");}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change background of your activity then try this,

```
View root = findViewById(R.id.main);
root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

so your full activity code would look something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Random r = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View root = findViewById(R.id.main);
}

public void calculate(View v){
    EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
    String num1=(number1text.getText().toString());
    String ans=num1;

    TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);    
    boolean value = r.nextBoolean();
    if(value==true){
    answer.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    answer.setText("It is a cause for celebration!                    So CELEBRATE!");}
    else{
    root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    answer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    answer.setText("Exciting, but not a cause for celebration!");}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```